# Magento file upload enhancement using jQuery - getting upload to add to cart

Tags: jquery, file, magento, upload, cart

I’ve (very roughly) integrated jQuery to enhance Magento’s file upload feature, however, I’ve yet to get the uploaded image to save across to the cart, ie, the filename doesn’t appear in the cart and consequently the user receives a validation error that a product option is required.

http://hotdiggity.com.au/installs/magento/tshirt.html

It’s working successfully on this site:

http://topiono.de/index.php/oelbilder-vom-foto/portraits-personen.html

Any suggestions would be appreciated please.

Answer (score 0):

it is because you did not specify the extensions allowed in the file upload field. Example if you are trying to upload a jpg you must put jpg in the allowed extensions or jpeg if you have more then one it would be

> jpg,jpeg,gif,png